# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Connection has been administratively disabled by console/admin command

Tags: java, sql, spring, tomcat, weblogic12c

We are getting the following error in a Spring/myBatis application that is deployed to Weblogic 12c

ERROR LoggingAspect                   - Exception : org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException:

#### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Connection has been administratively disabled by console/admin command. Try later. java.lang.Exception: It was disabled at Thu Sep 18 12:17:20 CDT 2014

```
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnv.disable(ConnectionEnv.java:380)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperImpl.removeConnFromPoolIfFatalError(JDBCWrapperImpl.java:159)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.XAConnection.invocationExceptionHandler(XAConnection.java:167)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.XAConnection.rollback(XAConnection.java:892)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection.checkConnection(JTAConnection.java:113)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection.checkConnection(JTAConnection.java:74)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.preInvocationHandler(Connection.java:98)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection.getAutoCommit(JTAConnection.java:347)
    at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.openConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:84)
    at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.getConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:69)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.getConnection(BaseExecutor.java:271)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.prepareStatement(ReuseExecutor.java:72)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.doQuery(ReuseExecutor.java:53)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:259)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:132)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:115)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:104)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:98)
```

This application is being developed on Tomcat and is working fine in the development environment.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out we had deployed the XA Drivers JDBC to Weblogic 12C when we really needed the Standard JDBC Drivers in this environment.

Thanks,

Tom